# redux update delete add value to object inside object by id if exist or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

hello I would like to update, delete and add value inside my redux store, my API return object of map for example

```
carList:{
"bmw" : [
   {
            "id": "C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8C3",
            "buyDate": "2000-02-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "sellDate": "2022-02-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "carID": "bmw",
            "color": "red"
        },
{
            "id": "C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8A3",
            "buyDate": "2010-03-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "sellDate": "2019-01-12T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "carID": "bmw",
            "color": "blue"
        }
],
"Ford" : [
   {
            "id": "C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8C3",
            "buyDate": "2000-02-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "sellDate": "2022-02-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "carID": "Ford",
            "color": "red"
        },
{
            "id": "C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8A3",
            "buyDate": "2010-03-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "sellDate": "2019-01-12T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "carID": "Ford",
            "color": "blue"
        }
]

}
```

and I dont know how to make cases in reducer for this simple code.

My insert update and delete object looks like

```
{
            "id": "C4FC3AS3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8A3",
            "buyDate": "2020-03-07T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "sellDate": "2021-01-12T19:33:02.613+00:00",
            "carID": "Ford",
            "color": "blue"
        }
```

```
 case DELETE_CAR:
            return { ...state,
                carList : Object
                    .keys(carList)
                    .filter(key => key !== action.payload.carID)
                    .reduce((obj, key) => { obj[key] = carList[key]; return obj; }, {} ) };


  case ADD_CAR: return {
            ...state,
            carList : state.carList [action.payload.carID]=  [...state.carList [action.payload.carID],action.payload]
        };
```

Comment: case DELETE_CAR: return {

            ...state,
            carList : Object.keys(carList).filter(key =>
                key !== action.payload.carID).reduce((obj, key) =>
                {
                    obj[key] = carList[key];
                    return obj;
                }, {}
            )
        };

Comment: Im trying to delete for the first step and I dont know how to move one

Comment: Which one did you want to delete? Please provide the id. What result did you get for your solution?

Comment: I would like to delete object in arrays like this one C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8A3 or that one C4FC3DC3-4C88-EC11-97A5-B07D6412D8A3